How to prove this inequality relating to Bernoulli trials?
The inequality is verbally intuitive, however an algebraic approach seems to be not as easy:
Consider $n$ Bernoulli trials, where for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, the $i$ th trial has probability $p_i$ of success, and let $X$ be the random variable denoting the total number of successes. Let $p\geq p_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ .Prove that for $1\leq k\leq n$,
$$\Pr(X<k)\ge\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom ni p^{i}\left(1-p\right)^{n-i} $$
Then, I thought by complement,
$$Pr(X\geq k)\leq\sum_{i=k}^{n}\binom ni p^{i}\left(1-p\right)^{n-i}$$
using markov's inequality, the task turns to prove that $E\left(X\right)\leq k\sum $, but for some reason I got stuck in there.
I don't know if its from my lack of insight or the bound was too lose so it turned to be unproductive, but I would like to know if there were a way to continue from there. Otherwise, what is another way to solve?

Actually the last inequality (using markov) seems to be not even weak, but wrong.

You have used $i$ in two different senses, to index the trials and to index the sum. It might be better to avoid this.

Also related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003520/probability-the-number-of-successes-of-n-bernoulli-trials-is-less-than-k-exc
